# Maximize with manipulate

Tags: mathematical-optimization, evaluation, linear-algebra

Iam trying to include a manipulate to NMaximize function to see how the output values are changing for p and t. By varying the variable w, x, y and z. Kindly please help me to resolve this, the file in attachment
Thanks

```
Manipulate[[NMaximize[{
    (*Objective function*)
    -6 p + 92 t,
    (*Constraints*)
    -0.3 p + 12 t >= (w - 11.81) &&
     -4 p + 34 t >= (x - 228.92) &&
     -3 p + 133 t == (y - 163.28) &&
     6 p - 92 t >= (z - 128.69),
    p >= 0 &&
     t >= 0},
   {p, t}]],
 {w, 6, 16}, {x, 170, 200}, {y, 150, 300}, {z, 50, 200}]
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Notice no change when moving the `w` and `x` sliders. May be you need to change the range for them as needed for your problem.

### code

```
ClearAll[p, t];
Manipulate[
 NMaximize[{
   (*Objective function*)-6 p + 92 t,
   (*Constraints*)-0.3 p + 12 t >= (w - 11.81) && -4 p + 
      34 t >= (x - 228.92) && -3 p + 133 t == (y - 163.28) && 
    6 p - 92 t >= (z - 128.69), p >= 0 && t >= 0}, {p, t}
  ]
 ,
 {{w, 6, "w"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x, 120, "x"}, 100, 170, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y, 150, "y"}, 100, 300, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{z, 50, "z"}, 1, 200, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 TrackedSymbols :> {w, x, y, z}]
```

Comment: Nasser, this answer might be improved by informing the asker where they went wrong? Very nice otherwise!